# Geting error:Loop must iterate over collection: Account

Tags: trigger

```
trigger LatestOppCreatDate on Opportunity  (after INSERT) {
    List <Id> accountIds = new List <Id>();
    List <Account> lstAccountsToUpdate = new List <Account>();
    For(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        accountIds.add(opp.PartnerAccountId);
    }   
   Account AccountsToUpdate = [ Select ID,LatestOpportunityCreatedDate__c from Account where ID In: accountIds ];
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        for ( Account acc : AccountsToUpdate){
            if( acc.ID == opp.PartnerAccountId ){
                acc.LatestOpportunityCreatedDate__c = date.newinstance(opp.CreatedDate.year(), opp.CreatedDate.month(), opp.CreatedDate.day());
            lstAccountsToUpdate.add(acc);
            }
        }
    }
    update lstAccountsToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, loop must iterate over collection. You are currently trying to loop over `AccountsToUpdate` which is not declared as a collection instead you have declared it as `Account` whereas it should be `List<Account>`.

The SOQL which you have written will return you `List<Account>`, so you will have to make below changes in your code

Replace below code

```
Account AccountsToUpdate = [ Select ID,LatestOpportunityCreatedDate__c from Account where ID In: accountIds ];
```

with

```
List<Account> AccountsToUpdate = [ Select ID,LatestOpportunityCreatedDate__c from Account where ID In: accountIds ];
```

Comment: List<Account> AccountsToUpdate = [ Select ID,LatestOpportunityCreatedDate__c from Account where ID In: accountIds ];Thanks Vijay:)

Comment: @SharathchowdaryY Glad to help you :)